# Blacklist [holy-war]

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-blacklist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Let's nuke the catch-all tags](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2373/lets-nuke-the-catch-all-tags)

We have an artifact from the Antedisciplining period that should be removed: [holy-war](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/holy-war), which is obviously not the type of question we're looking for here.

Can it be purged with the fire from a thousand suns?

Comment: Or with the fire from the breath of one Trogdor. That'd work too.

Comment: I've always been suspicious of questions that were tagged "holy-war" by the OP. Isn't that a lot like tagging them "close-me"?

Comment: The Antedisciplining Period? Lol

Comment: Also seems like a meta tag, it tells us nothing about the actual content of the question.  Kill it :)  Wipe both it and it's ancestors off the face of the planet.

Comment: Where was the mandate for you to do this exactly?