# What is a point of the holy war tag?

Tags: support, tags

I have seen [this request](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1702/blacklist-holy-war), but the [holy-war](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/holy-war)is still there. Therefore I guess it should be somehow used. My question is in what kind of questions should that tag be used?

Comment: This tag should not be used and we need to remove it. (Leaving this as a comment, cause this is the "short version". I'll make a proper answer later unless someone beats me to it.)

Answer (score 6):

Y'know the kind of question where there's no real answer, everyone just states a preference, and then argues vehemently that it's the One True Way?

[image: Endianness is a holy war of sorts]

They're great fun of course. Nothing beats layin' a good beating on those fools who think curly braces should be put at the ends of lines to save space. But rarely is anything accomplished or truly answered.

If you see a question that matches this description, don't tag it [holy-war](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/holy-war) - just close it / delete it.

Comment: There is http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/121151/office-lights-on-or-off-in-programming-department-how-to-decide tagged with it that I find fun. Other then that, I would expect such questions to be closed as not constructive right away :)

Comment: Sometimes, you won't necessarily know how unconstructive a question is until you see the answers roll in.

Answer (score 2):

It ought to have been a self-referential best-of sort of tag for those who know that what they're getting in to is the stuff that will raise the most possible eyebrows and generate the maximum amount of vitriol.

AKA flamebait.

For instance, I asked [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9521/what-constitutes-a-dead-programming-language) back when programmer.SE had a spark of tempered genius (that, by the way, was never in any way headed toward programmers Reddit or 4Chan or anything web-despicable no matter what they tell ya).  I asked it because I was waiting for someone to say something cruel about Delphi and then have an excuse to tell them why they're wrong.

Some may say that's trolling, but as a [Catechist](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/4/peter-turner), I can tell you that sometimes all you can do is ask leading questions.